# ¿Cómo crear prueba unitaria con JUnit de un servicio rest java?

Tags: java, oracle, spring-boot, junit, junit-5

Tengo el siguiente servicio que recibe dos parametros del frontend, lo que hace es buscar en la base de datos (Oracle) a traves de esos parametros recibidos y los muestra, cómo puedo realizar una prueba unitaria con JUnit de este servicio? que pruebe su funcionamiento en el happy path y cayendo en la excepcion

Quisiera saber si la excepcion que agregue en el controller y service esta correcta, o le faltaria algo mas como una traza? o si puedo optimizar mi código para que sea mas entendible y funcional

```java
    @CrossOrigin(origins ="http://localhost:4200", maxAge = 3600)
        @RestController
        public class ConsultarValoresController {
            
            @Autowired
            private ConsultarValoresService  consultarValoresService  

            @GetMapping()
            public List<ValoresDTO> listar(@RequestParam (required=false, value="fechaInicio") Integer fechaInicio, 
        @RequestParam (required=false, value="fechaFin") Integer fechaFin) throws Exception  {
                List<ValoresDTO> listaValores = new ArrayList<ValoresDTO>();
            try {
                listaValores =  consultarValoresService.consultarValores(fechInicio, fechFinal);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                LOGGER.error("Error in DataValues ");
                throw e;
            }
            return listaValores;
            }
```

```java
     @Service
        public class ConsultarValoresServiceImpl implements ConsultarValoresService{
            
        @Autowired
            private ConsultarValoresRepository consultarValoresRepository 
            
            @Override
            public List<ValoresDTO> consultarValores(Integer fechaInicio, Integer fechaFin) throws Exception {
                try {
                Integer ini = fechaInicio;
                Integer fin = fechaFin;
                return consultarValoresRepository.consultarValoresBd(ini, fin);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                LOGGER.error("An error ocurred looking for Data Values");
                throw e;
            }
    }
```

```java
    public interface ConsultarValoresRepository  extends JpaRepository<ValoresDto, Integer>{                
                @Query(value="select * from TABLE_VALORES t where t.fechaRegistro between ?1 and ?2", nativeQuery =true)
                List<ValoresDto> consultarValoresBd(Integer fechInicio, Integer fechaFin);
        }
```

Comment: Para pruebas unitarias, no es "un servicio REST", es simplemente una clase más que se prueba como cualquier otra (inyección de mockups de dependencias e invocación de los métodos). Si quieres hacer pruebas de como procesa mensajes REST, eso ya no son pruebas unitarias, ya que pruebas la clase y todo el framework REST.

Comment: ok y como seria entonces? esa es mi duda

Comment: Las pruebas unitarias son unitarias, así que no pruebas tooodo el camino del controlador al repositorio, eso es end-to-end. En las unitarias pruebas cada componente de eso, haces mock del resto y pruebas que ese método haga lo que debería

Comment: @SJuan76 para pruebas unitarias tambien se puede probar como servicio rest usando [tag:rest-assured] o `MockMvc` que es la forma en que se prueba en Spring, aunque técnicamente ya sería una prueba de integración

Answer (score 0):

Ni sirve ni esta correcta.

La idea de atrapar una excepción es para manejarla y evitar su propagación.

Si poner que atrape `Exception`, atrapará todos los throwable que no sean un error crítico de sistema indistintamente, y eso a pesar de que crees que es algo muy inteligente, indica que no tienes la menor idea de que excepciones puede producir tu código y que por lo tanto ni sabes como probarlo ni como garantizar que funciona como debería.

ahora que cada que atrapes algo lo propagues con un

```
throw e;
```

es como decir, sí, ya sé que algo salió mal pero no voy a hacer nada al respecto, es más te voy a mostrar el error con todos los detalles por si me quieres hackear